# Derby how to change port number

Tags: java, derby

In the Windows, I successfully modified Derby default port. But in the Linux version, in the bin dir, I can't find the similar file as derby_common.bat in windows.

How to change port number of Derby in Linux ?

Thanks

Comment: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.5/adminguide/tadminappssettingportnumbers.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the latest version 10.11, the [documentation](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/adminguide/index.html) says (search for "Setting port numbers"):

By default, the Derby Network Server listens on TCP/IP port number
1527. If you want to use a different port number, you can specify it on the command line when starting the Network Server.

For example:

```
java org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl start -p 1088
```

However, it is better to specify the port numbers by using any of the following methods:

- Change the startNetworkServer.bat or startNetworkServer.ksh script
- Use the derby.drda.portNumber property in derby.properties

Comment: if I use derby.properties, where I should put ? do I need to change something else ? thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? Was there something you didn't understand?